# Emails alerts not coming through when an order is placed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone experiencing lately an issue with delayed or no order alerts to the website email with woocommerce?
This begun about 2 months, when a customer places an order, i can not receive an email alert on it, till i check the backend, all emails have been set for receiving the orders in the Woocommerce emails section.

I tried deactivating all plugins to see if there is a conflict but it seems its general with woocommerce, since another different website begun having this same issue.

Any help with this will be much appreciated guys!!

Comment: Do you have issues with other emails ? For example from contact forms ? That sounds like issue with your email server. Try installing SMTP and test if its sending emails.

Comment: Hi Martin, the contact forms too are not working, i think the issue is with the email server, i have installed SMTP and it caught some errors while sending emails. Do you have any free SMTP plugin recommendation i could use for this fix please?

Comment: I use most of the time WP Mail SMTP by WPForms another option is to set your own config for smtp. The hosting could help you with that if you want to avoid plugins.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is solved now, i realized my hosting provider had blocked mail for my website via the cpanel. its now fixed. i appreciate alot!

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now, i realised My Hosting Provider had blocked my website's Mailing system and we have unblocked it and all seems ok now.